# Is there a better way of including code containing &lt; &gt;

Tags: feature-request, source-code, rendering

I frequently see examples of code containing < and > characters which get rendered incorrectly, because the tags aren't quoted as &lt; and &gt;. This seems to happen when using `<pre><code>` rather than indenting by 4 spaces. (See e.g. [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4e42e1fe-ef8f-4722-b717-2a799b8f749e/view-source))

This often happens with:

- code containing generics in Java and C#
- C `#include` statements
- testing for greater-than and less-than

The first one is particularly nasty, because the code doesn't look necessarily wrong (e.g. the user entered `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`, but it appears as `List list = new ArrayList();`;

Please could StackOverflow either warn the user about this before posting or actually perform the rendering expected?

(Apologies if this is a duplicate; it's hard to search for `<` and `>`!)

Comment: I'm hesitant, but my finger is twitchy wanting to tag this as a bug...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a high enough arbitrary number, in this case, **2000**, you could go help them out and edit the question yourself to improve the formatting.

Or you could flag it down for a mod to come along and fix it up for them.

Either way, it will leave an edit trail and allow the asker to then, if so inclined, look over the edit history and see what was done to achieve that formatting for future reference.

Comment: The correct solution is escaping all text inside code blocks. As I can't conceive anyone posting a link within code, SOFU could just escape all text within code blocks, and keep working the same way it does now. People can help **in the meantime**.

Comment: I do make the edits when I notice them. My point was you have to spot it (there's no visual difference between a <pre> block and a 4-space indented one unless you look at the markdown)