# Can we have the pre tag work as the code tag does for angle brackets?

Tags: feature-request, design, pre

[Extends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/is-there-a-better-way-of-including-code-containing-lt-gt).

The <code> tag works really great:
`test < less than > but markup still works`

< and > don't get parsed out as tags.

The <pre> tag operates different:

```
test  but markup still works
```

Here the < less than > got gobbled up somehow inside the <pre> tag.

I know you can use 4 spaces but I find it irritating.

Anyway, it'd be great if the <pre> tag could act more like the <code> tag wrt < and >

Answer (score 2):

Indent by 4 spaces.

The only reason to use `<pre>` is if you want to avoid syntax highlighting -- and that plus <> in the content is rare enough that this is low-pri.

Comment: But I __love__ pre!!  And I'm not a 4 space indenter..

Comment: @Jeff: if you copy a long piece of code  ``<pre><code>`` is so much better that indenting every line by 4 characters

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano Select the block of code and press `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get this. If you want to use HTML, then use HTML - HTML requires escaping certain "special" characters.

If you want to use Markdown, then use Markdown...